# Use r10k with separate module repositories

Tags: puppet, r10k

I have a working setup of Puppet with Master and Agent. Now I'm trying to use r10k to manage Puppet code. My goal is that on each `git push`of a code change the Puppet code below `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments` on the Puppet Master gets updated automatically.

While this seems to work for one monolithic control repository containing all modules, I'm not getting it to work if custom modules are in separate Git repositories.

My setup is as follows:

**r10k configuration** in `/etc/puppetlabs/r10k/r10k.yaml`:

```
sources:
  operations:
    remote: '/srv/git/puppet.git'
    basedir: '/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments'
```

**Central control repository** `/srv/git/puppet.git` containing branches `production` and `testing`, each with:

- A `manifests/site.pp` with node configurations, e.g. `node default { contain mymodule }`
- A `Puppetfile` with external module references

The `Puppetfile` for `testing` would look like e.g.

```
mod 'mymodule',
  :git => 'file:///srv/git/mymodule.git',
  :ref => 'HEAD'
```

while for `production` it would look like e.g.

```
mod 'mymodule',
  :git => 'file:///srv/git/mymodule.git',
  :ref => 'stable'
```

(Until this works I only have branch `production` and reference to `HEAD`.)

**Another Git repository for each custom module**, e.g. `/srv/git/mymodule.git`

**Git Hooks** to run r10k whenever `git push` is executed:

- `/srv/git/puppet.git/hooks/post-receive`

  with content `r10k deploy environment -pv`
- `/srv/git/mymodule.git/hooks/post-receive`

  with content `r10k deploy module mymodule -v`

The hooks get executed, since upon `git push` I get output like

```
remote: INFO     -> Deploying environment /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production
remote: INFO     -> Environment production is now at 991830eb1561cddd7970be4152748168df52ef79
remote: INFO     -> Deploying Puppetfile content /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mymodule
```

and

```
remote: INFO     -> Deploying module /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mymodule
```

My problem is that - despite this output - changes pushed to the module's repository are not reflected by the files below `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments`.

---

**Edit**

Elaborating a bit on my intended workflow:

- My control repo has two branches, `production` and `testing`, while the module repository has only one branch `master`. I thought it would be easier that way, especially to avoid merge issues. But considering that in Git merges can be restricted to fast-forward, and r10k has active support for the tracking of branches, my workflow might actually be easier using the branches `production` and `testing` for the module repositories as well. I would then work (develop) on `testing` and only switch to `production` to execute something like `git merge --ff-only testing`.
- My first thought was to create a Git tag `stable` for the module repository which I move to the current commit every now and then, i.e. staying in the `master` branch all the time without any merging done at all. But a fast-forward-only merge between branches can also save me from merge conflicts, so there's probably no reason to avoid branches. Also I could get the same workflow on both the control repo and the module repos.
- I'm only starting to learn about Puppet with two virtual machines, one Puppet master and one agent. I'll add another VM agent and then point one to the `production` environment and the other one to `testing` so I can verify my workflow while building a usable Puppet configuration for the agents. For now I'll simply set the environment in each agent's `puppet.conf`.
- Later I'll use real Linux boxes and map one agent to `testing` and all others to `production`. The master will be on another box and set up manually.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Try to use `r10k deploy module -e ${YOUR_ENVIRONMENT} ${YOUR_MODULE} -v`.

Comment: I'm using r10k 2.5.5. Same behavior when specifying the environment with `-e`.

Comment: When running the module deploy with `-v debug2` the output ends with `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mymodule is already at Git ref HEAD`.

Comment: Maybe it's my limited knowledge, but, being a long time r10k user as well: What should `HEAD` be doing in there? I newer saw this in use like this. Do you want to track a branch? If so, use `{branch,ref} => ${BRANCHNAME}`.

Comment: You're totally right, `:branch => master` does what I thought `:ref => HEAD` would do. I had tried something with `:branch` which didn't work when I started trying with `:ref => HEAD`, but `:branch => master` does work. To keep the setup simple I wanted to avoid branching. Instead I wanted to always use the latest commit of the module repository for testing and use another `stable` tag for production which I move forward whenever the code is in acceptable shape. Any ideas for the `stable` part? Feel free to "answer". Thanks a lot so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question, and the comments:

> My problem is that - despite this output - changes pushed to the module's repository are not reflected by the files below `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments`.

`r10k` doesn't know about `HEAD`. `HEAD` is non deterministic, so it's not possible to use it like this.

If you want to track a `branch`, use something like:

```
mod 'mymodule',
  :git => 'file:///srv/git/mymodule.git',
  :ref => 'master'
```

> To keep the setup simple I wanted to avoid branching. Instead I wanted to always use the latest commit of the module repository for testing and use another stable tag for production which I move forward whenever the code is in acceptable shape.

Honestly, I'm unsure how your workflow looks like:

- You've got a control repo with two branches, `master` and `testing`. `master` is the stable, production code, while you're using `testing` for development?
- You're pushing new code to `testing`, and once it reaches a state you're comfortable with, you're merging `testing` into `master`?
- After this, you would like to tag the current state in `master` as `stable`, which your agents should use?
- How does the rest of your infrastructure look like? How many agents are in place? How do you test your code, i.e. how do you tell {one,all} (?) agents: "Please use this code coming out of this environment"?
- Follow up to the above: If you've code in `master` and `testing`, how do your agents know which environment to use?
- If you could elaborate on the above points and tell me some more details (and please add this to your question, the comments might be too limited for that), I might able to help and extend this answer.
- Anyway, good luck! `puppet` and `r10k`, especially if coupled with git hooks, are an awesome setup! Using this myself, it's just great! :)

Additional info:

- Thanks for elaborating on your workflow.
- If you aren't that versatile yet with git, and especially if you're doing a lot of branching and merging and are afraid of merge conflicts, make sure to read about [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), which does

  > reapply commits on top of another base tip
- Say you're in the following situation:

  - You're branching of `master` to `feature1`.
  - You do some work in `file1:3-6` in `feature1`.
  - You're changing `file1:7-10` directly in `master` to fix a pressing bug.
  - You want to merge `feature1` back into `master`.
  - Normally, at this point, you would get a merge conflict, because the same file was modified in both branches.
  - If you do `git rebase master` while on `feature1` before merging, this will "pull" the latest state / commit(s) into `feature1`, in this case the bug fix.
  - Now do the merge, without conflicts.
- I wouldn't limit myself to only one branch in the module repositories. How do you handle testing new code inside there? It's not only your control repo which needs to enhance over time.
- To make this comfortable, use another feature of `r10k`:

  ```
  # Track control branch and fall-back to master if no matching branch exists
  mod 'mymodule',
    :git => 'file:///srv/git/mymodule.git',
    :branch => :control_branch,
    :default_branch => 'master'
  ```
- This will allow you to do the following, for example in a situation where you would like to develop a new feature in your module:

  - In your control repo, branch of `master` to `testing`.
  - In your module repo, branch of `master` to `testing`.
  - Without changing your `Puppetfile`, your puppet agent which uses the `testing` branch of your control repo now *also* uses the `testing` branch of your module repo.
  - Develop up until you're satisfied.
  - In your module repo, merge `testing` into `master`.
  - The new code you've developed will now go to all your puppet agents which use the production code, i.e. the `master` branch of your control repo.
- One last note, for now: It sounds like you're the only person developing code, so maybe that's not that important for you, but just to let you know:

  - If two branches are too limited, it's quite possible to use a different environment during a puppet agent run without modifying the config, but via supplying a cli param:

    ```
    puppet agent -t --environment ${FEATURE_BRANCH}
    ```
- That's all for now I can think of. Hope this helps, again, good luck and all the best!

Comment: I think these 3 tips will get me a very powerful workflow. Time to roll up my sleeves. Thank you so much - and all the best!